# Hiding div in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation, pytest

I want to hide header when I'm taking screenshot using selenium python.

```py
find = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, elm.header)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].style.display = 'none';", find)
```

Comment: whats the question? you got any error?

Comment: can you share the url?

Comment: Basically I'm trying to hide header while taking screen shot, but when I run the above command header didn't hide still showing when taking screen shot.